# Flexslider path image problems

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, flexslider

I have a problem with flexslider in Drupal7. The problem is that the path where the images are uploaded by flexlider is different then the path that is used to read them.

When I upload the images with fleshlier to the server they are put in the folder sites/default/files/fleshlier.

But fleshlier reads the images located in the folder sites/default/files/styles/fleshlier_full/public/fleshlier.

So when I upload them fleshlier can not read them until I put them in the right folder.

How I can change those paths?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here about path: you upload to sites/default/files/fleshlier, then Drupal creates a styled copy of your  images into sites/default/files/styles/fleshlier_full/public/fleshlier.
If something is not properly working, check file system permission. More at
http://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/image

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thank you augusto, you pointed me in the right direction.
Also this [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/image-styles-not-generated-with-drupal-7-on-iis-6) was very interesting.